# Integrate.quad doesn't work properly

Tags: python, lambda, scipy

I want to code this:

[image: http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cint_%7B0.322411516161%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%28108e%5Ex%20-%20150%29function%5Bselection%5D%28%29%20dx]

where

```
params = (-0.00019942774322628663, 0.017096351295537309)
functions = {'1': lambda x:norm.cdf(x,loc=params[0],scale=params[1]), '2': lambda x:laplace.cdf(x,loc=params[0],scale=params[1])}
```

So I've written this:

```
print integrate.quad(lambda x : ((108*numpy.exp(x))-150)*functions[selection](), 0.322411516161, numpy.inf)
```

where selection is given by the user. I get this error:

```
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

EDIT: I've made the following changes reading the answer:

```
print integrate.quad(lambda x : ((108*numpy.exp(x))-150)*functions[selection](x), 0.322411516161, numpy.inf)
```

and I get

```
 IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be underestimated.warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
 (inf, nan)
```

Comment: Your integral diverges.  Either of the CDF functions in `selection` approaches 1 as x goes to infinity.  The integrand is the CDF multiplied by `108*exp(x) - 150`.  So for large x, the integrand is effectively `108*exp(x) - 150`, and the integral of that over [x0, infinity) diverges.  Double-check the problem that you are trying to solve, to make sure you are integrating the correct function.  Perhaps you mean to use the PDF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) instead of the CDF?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the error is because your `lambda` is

```
lambda x : ((108*numpy.exp(x))-150)*functions[selection]()
```

when it should be

```
lambda x : ((108*numpy.exp(x))-150)*functions[selection](your_arg_here)
```

where `your_arg_here` is what you want to pass to your selection function.

In other words, the `lambda` which is generating the error about not having enough args is whichever `lambda` you're referencing with `selection`, not the `lambda` you have defined for `integrate.quad`.

Not sure what arg you'd want to pass to your selection function, or I'd give a more complete answer. I'm assuming it's `x`, though, and in that case, your `lambda` would be:

```
lambda x : ((108*numpy.exp(x))-150)*functions[selection](x)
```

**In response to the updated question:**

```
IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be underestimated.warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
 (inf, nan)
```

is just letting you know that the integral diverges (goes off to infinity), and there is some floating point erors occuring. The integral diverging makes sense since e^x is unbounded as x ---> inf, and `function[selection]` is calculating a cdf value, which means it's bounded by [0,1]. Based on some quick testing, it looks like `function[selection]` will always be 1 for values greater than 1. Thus as x-->inf, `function[selection]` is 1, and e^x goes to infinity, hence the divergence.

Comment: Thanks mate. I've done that but instead of x I've passed params(functions inside the dictionary need params,Am I right? )and I get a new error: error: Supplied function does not return a valid float. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: The lambda functions inside the dictionary do not need `params`, they already have `params` as part of their definition. So you definitely don't need to pass `params` in as an argument. I really do think you just want to pass `x`, like I have at the bottom of my answer. I'd have to see your exact changes to help you further, I think. Make sure to upvote/accept my answer if you deem it answered your question!

Comment: Also, you can always open another question if you're having other problems unrelated to the question you've asked above.

Comment: thanks. I've edited the post with your advice and the error I get.